# Есть ли в babel полифилл для Node.contains?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babel

Столкнулся с тем, что ИЕ11 не поддерживает Node.contains. В связи с этим появился вопрос есть ли в  babel полифилл для Node.contains или что можно сделать для поддержки Node.contains?

Сборщик webpack. В проекте используются Typescript и React.

Comment: Может, лучше просто прекратить поддержку ИЕ11?

Comment: На проекте ключевые клиенты все еще используют эту мерзость. Приходится страдать.